# Why can't I install matplotlib or pandas with pip OR miniconda?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pip, anaconda

Windows 10
Python 3.1

I have a script written that requires pandas and matplotlib. However, I'm having trouble installing either even though I've tried both pip in cmd and conda in Miniconda.

Here's the error I get when trying to install either via pip in cmd (ie `py -m pip install -U matplotlib`:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Nick\miniconda3\envs\name_of_my_env\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Nick\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jlytfo2_\\matplotlib_5bffd16903a8431f98af43098502973c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Nick\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jlytfo2_\\matplotlib_5bffd16903a8431f98af43098502973c\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-3tmzcurv'
       cwd: C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jlytfo2_\matplotlib_5bffd16903a8431f98af43098502973c\
  Complete output (551 lines):
```

In conda, when I try `conda install matplotlib`, I get this:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.1

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I'm really not sure what could be wrong since I didn't run into these problems when I installed these packages through similar means on my other PC, and I **definitely** do have Python 3.1 installed. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Python3.1 is a very old version so the libraries won't support it, use python3.8 or python3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a new environment and installing matplotlib and numpy in it directly as follows:

```
conda create --new env_nick python=3.8 numpy matplotlib
```

Then, activate the environment as

```
conda activate env_nick
```

Your python version is old and incompatible with some of the updated packages.

Comment: This worked! I have no idea why my environment(s) was operating in an older version of Python. I'll also note that since I use VS Code, I had to change the environment I was using to the one I created with this method, and am good to go now.

Answer (score 5):

## Conda 4.10 is incompatible with python 3.10.

You basically cannot install anything after creating and activating your python 3.10 environment. You cannot even install conda-build:

```
conda install conda-build -y
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - python=3.1
```

[Conda 4.10 contains python 3.9 and conda 4.11 contains python 3.10](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html), so your base environment should be compatible with the python version therein.

### If you need python 3.10+

If you need python 3.10 or newer, you must have conda 4.11 or newer. Install the desired conda version, or switch to the base environment and [update conda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/) using `conda update conda`.

### If you want to keep the old conda

Install another environment with python 3.9 or older like `conda create --name py39 python=3.9` and activate it.