# Trying to install Earth Engine on R; python=3.1 not available

Tags: python, r, google-earth-engine

I'm just trying to get to Hello World in rgee. When I run
`ee_install()`
I get

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.1
```

Same deal happens with

```
conda install -c conda-forge python=3.1
```

Comment: Have you crated an appropriate python/conda environment? 
Bit tough to guess but does not look like it. What OS are you on?

Comment: windows 10. probably not, very new to using R in conda

Comment: I think my "Rstudio environment" has python=3.10. For some reason when I run ee_install() it tries to install python=3.1. I get the same error when I try to install python=3.1

Comment: you probably should set up a conda env ie in a CONDA command prompt eg `conda create -n rgeenv python=3.1` outside of RStudio, install all the necessary packages there so after `conda activate rgeenv` do some  `conda install ... ` and then from within RStudio using `reticulate` do `use_condaenv("rgeenv")`

Answer (score 0):

## Conda 4.10 is incompatible with python 3.10.

I guess you have created a new conda environment with python, and the problem lies here.
Your issue is not specific to Earth Engine on R. You can resolve this issue using one of these workarounds:

- update conda to 4.11 or newer (however, it may require admin privileges)
- install an older version of python, e.g. 3.9 or older
- use pip or other package manager, but not conda