# PyTorch installation asks for python=3.1 . Python Version installed: 3.10.0

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytorch, conda, python-3.10

```
(pgqa) raphy@pc:~/pythonMatters/PathGenerator$ conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.1

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


(pgqa) raphy@pc:~/pythonMatters/PathGenerator$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.0
```

Tried installing PyTorch with pip but got these errors:

```
(pgqa) raphy@pc:~/pythonMatters/PathGenerator$ pip3 install torch==1.10.0+cpu 
torchvision==0.11.1+cpu torchaudio==0.10.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org
/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.10.0+cpu (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.10.0+cpu
```

O.S.: Ubuntu 20.04

pip version:

```
(pgqa) raphy@pc:~$ pip --version
pip 21.2.4 from /home/raphy/anaconda3/envs/pgqa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
(pgqa) raphy@pc:~$ pip3 --version
pip 21.2.4 from /home/raphy/anaconda3/envs/pgqa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

Python Version:

```
(pgqa) raphy@pc:~$ python --version
Python 3.10.0
```

Why does it asks for  python3.1 if the latest stable python version is 3.10 ?
How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Conda 4.10 is incompatible with python 3.10.

The reason you cannot install many packages with conda is that conda 4.10 has a known bug handling python 3.10. Update your conda to 4.11 or revert your python to 3.9 or older. [Read more here in this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69551793/cant-use-python-packages-in-r-cannot-import-name-read-csv-from-pandas-unk/70304326#70304326)

As a workaround, you can still try to use pip.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried upgrading your `pip`?
It works with following commands and versions:

$ python --version

```
 Python 3.8.10
```

$ pip --version

```
pip 21.3.1
```

$ pip install torch==1.10.0+cpu torchvision==0.11.1+cpu torchaudio==0.10.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html

[image]

Comment: `(pgqa) raphy@pc:~$ pip --version
pip 21.2.4 from /home/raphy/anaconda3/envs/pgqa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
(pgqa) raphy@pc:~$ pip3 --version
pip 21.2.4 from /home/raphy/anaconda3/envs/pgqa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
(pgqa) raphy@pc:~$ python --version
Python 3.10.0 .  `Are you suggesting me to downgrade both python and pip ?

Comment: Hi @Raphael10, I have tried with pip 21.3.1 and python 3.8 and it works fine. At this stage I am not able to confirm the same for python 3.10.0

Comment: Yes. It seems that the problem is with `python 3.10.0` :  (pgqa) raphy@pc:~$ python --version
Python 3.8.10
(pgqa) raphy@pc:~$ pip --version
pip 21.1.1 from /home/raphy/anaconda3/envs/pgqa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
(pgqa) raphy@pc:~$ pip3 install torch==1.10.0+cpu torchvision==0.11.1+cpu torchaudio==0.10.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html
Collecting torch==1.10.0+cpu
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.10.0%2Bcpu-cp38-cp38-linux

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/67669 I guess 3.10 is not supported yet,