# PyCharm doesn't recognize Python 3.10, how do I configure it?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to use Python 3.10 with PyCharm on Windows 10.

However, it gets recognized as Python 3.1 instead:

[image]

If I try to run my script, the interpreter complains that this version of Python is deprecated.

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: what version of **pyCharm** are you using?

Answer (score 16):

You are likely using an old PyCharm version. Python 3.10 is rather new. Update PyCharm to at least 2020.2. See the relevant ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42855.

Comment: Updating to the latest version of PyCharm indeed fixes this issue!

Comment: same here, was using pycharm 2020.  got the 3.1 not supported but I verified 3.10 with `python.exe --version`  updating to pycharm 2020, works with python 3.10.7 now.

Answer (score 1):

## Conda 4.10 is incompatible with python 3.10.

It is not an issue with PyCharm, but a known bug in conda. Update your conda to the newest, or install a miniconda that already has python 3.10.

[Read this SO answer for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304326/1837006)

Answer (score 0):

You can change what python you are using in **Settings -> Project: Python -> Project Interpreter**

If you don't find the version, you can add it clicking on the icon aside it and locating a python.exe script in your pc.

In my case the default directory for the python.exe is
**C:\Users<myUser>\PycharmProjects\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe**

so I assume you can just get you version from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and put it there.